Is this matrix adjugate's connection to combinatorial sequences known?
$\mathbf{SETUP}$
(Same setup as my previously posted question on determinants, but this time for the adjugate.)
For my theoretical physics PhD I have been studying a model that requires the inversion of an $n \times n$ matrix of this form:
$$
\mathbf{A}_n=
\begin{pmatrix}
        1  & -a_{12} & -a_{13} & -a_{14} & ... & -a_{1n} \\
        -a_{21}  & 1 & -a_{23} & -a_{24} & ... & -a_{2n} \\
        -a_{31}  & -a_{32} & 1 & -a_{34} & ... & -a_{3n} \\
        -a_{41}  & -a_{42} & -a_{43} & 1 & ... & -a_{4n} \\
        ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
        -a_{n1}  & -a_{n2} & -a_{n3} & -a_{n4} & ... & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
(The minus signs are important to the model but not relevant for this question.)
The diagonal entry of the adjugate of this matrix (the transpose of the matrix of cofactors; a matrix of submatrix determinants) is simply the determinant of the $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ version of the same matrix (see aforementioned previous question for what that pattern is).
However, a given non-diagonal entry of the adjugate of this matrix produces a number terms of $n^\text{th}$ order and less, which follow this triangle sequence of numbers:
https://oeis.org/A010027
$\mathbf{QUESTION}$
Is this connection known? What is an intuitive / specific / detailed reason for the connection?
This is a less famous sequence than my previous question, so it's harder to search for. I see no reference to this matrix on the OEIS page, though.
I know no mathematicians to ask directly so I figured here was a good place to see how well known are these sequences' connections to a matrix of this generalish sort of form.
$\mathbf{EXPLANATION \ OF \ RESULT}$
While I have a very satisfactory step-by-step explanation of how to arrive at these numbers for this off-diagonal adjugate matrix entry (a 'proof' of sorts, to a physicist's standard at least), it is a bit long for this question; and anyhow it doesn't clarify to me what the exact connection would be to this particular sequence, beyond its obvious similarity in being about patterns in general permutations.
P.S. As before, even if this is known and not new, I would like to add it to the OEIS comments if possible - I am in the process of requesting an account.

I have since found a way to express this sequence using the falling factorial $(n)k = n\mathcal{P}k \equiv n!/(n-k)!$ multiplied by the cumulative sum $F_j = \sum{m=0}^j E_m$ of the alternating sum of fractional factorials $E_i = \sum_{m=0}^i \frac{(-1)^m}{m!}$: $T_\alpha(n) = (n-2){\alpha - 1} \times F{\alpha - 1}$
